# How can I make a looped animated drawing of a Chinese character from Hanzi Writer to use on Chinese.SE?

Tags: localization, animations

[Hanzi Writer](https://hanziwriter.org/) makes beautiful animations for Chinese characters.  They look like the following (but animated):

[image]

These animations would be useful at [Chinese.SE](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/) for questions about handwriting, but Chinese.SE doesn't accept javascript.  To give a concrete example, for the question [Why does my handwritten 尽 look so ugly?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/36895/why-does-my-handwritten-%e5%b0%bd-look-so-ugly) I'd like an animated [尽](https://makemeahanzi.herokuapp.com/#/codepoint/23613).

I asked on [meta.Chinese.SE about this](https://chinese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1681/what-are-the-chances-of-supporting-hanzi-writer-animated-characters) and Don Kirkby whipped up [an example on meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/344086#344086).  There's also Hanzi Writer [a demo site](https://hanziwriter.org/demo.html) and its possible to link to specific characters drawn by Hanzi Writer (as above, with 尽).

**Question**: How can I make a looped animated drawing of a Chinese character from Hanzi Writer to use on Chinese.SE?

I feel like there should be some way to do this, perhaps just a workaround.

---

*Update*: Using screen recording software, [I managed to create an animation](https://chinese.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1718/8099):

[image]

It's a bit of a hack, though, and loses some quality.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about using a web application as it's defined on [help/on-topic].

Comment: Sorry, I'm new here.  Would it be possible to clarify what's inappropriate about this please?  I checked the help center prior to posting, and it seemed on-topic.  Also, do you have a suggestion as to where would be appropriate to ask this question?  (Super User?)  I don't mind if this question is migrated.

Comment: Hanzi Writer is not a Web Application as it's defined on [help/on-topic], it's a JavaScript library. Regarding were to ask I suggest you to post a question on [meta.se] to ask for a site recommendation. Please bear in mind that questions about how to use Chinese.SE should be posted on Meta Chinese.SE.